# Send audio file via Andoid phone call without internet

Tags: android, root, phone-call, android-kernel, 4g

I have 2 Android phone (I can be rooted on them) . I can write on each of them Application. But I have **no internet** for those phone.

I want to send audio file from 1 phone to another via phone call and that audio file will be **binary same**.

I know that in phone there is audio encoder that may change the data (encoding/pack/compress data) can I skip on this module so I can send audio file via phone call that will be exactly same binary?

Comment: What does that have to do with programming?

Comment: Just play the tape for one phone and listen on the other side..

Comment: @blackapps . a) I want to do that automatically b) play tape will not get binary same on the other side.

Comment: Can you not send them via bluetooth?

Comment: @Darkman. No only phone call.

Comment: One possibility would be an audio encoder and decoder that will encode the file bit by bit into audio frequences. Ie something like for bit `0` play a sound of 1000Hz and for bit `1` play a sound of 2000Hz. On the receiving side do the opposite, ie if you recognize 1000Hz that stands for `0` and 2000Hz stands for `1`. Of course you would need to find a bitrate at which encoding and decoding will work reliably ... you could also use more distinct frequencies to be able to "transfer" multiple bits with one sound. Ie more or less what ancient modems or fax machines did ...